# upload a page blob to azure using REST API python

Tags: python, linux, azure, storage, blob

please how can i upload the blob with type page to azure this page is a VHD file "large content" please follow the following function:

```
def upload(blob_service, container_name, blob_name, file_path):
blob_service.create_container(container_name, None, None, False)
blob_service.put_blob(container_name, blob_name, '', "PageBlob")
data_sent=0
sent = 0
block_ids = []
block_ids = []
index = 0
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(PAGE_SIZE)
        if data:
            length = len(data)
            #block_id = base64.b64encode(str(index))
            x_range     = 'bytes={}-{}'.format(index, index + pageSize - 1)
            blob_service.put_page(container_name, blob_name, data, x_ms_range = x_range,x_ms_page_write = 'clear')
            block_ids.append(block_id)
            index += 1
            data_sent += PAGE_SIZE
            sent = data_sent/(1024*1024)
            sys.stdout.write("\rUploaded data = %d MB"%sent)
            sys.stdout.flush()           
        else:
            break

blob_service.put_block_list(container_name, blob_name, block_ids)
```

and the Error was:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "ehcpazurenew.py", line 331, in <module>
  upload(blob_service,container_name,blob_name,file_path)
  File "ehcpazurenew.py", line 250, in upload
  blob_service.put_blob(container_name, blob_name, '', "PageBlob")
  File "/home/ahmed/Desktop/azure/storage/blobservice.py", line 486, in put_blob
  response = self._perform_request(request)
  File "/home/ahmed/Desktop/azure/storage/storageclient.py", line 145, in _perform_request
  _storage_error_handler(e)
  File "/home/ahmed/Desktop/azure/storage/__init__.py", line 757, in _storage_error_handler
  return _general_error_handler(http_error)
  File "/home/ahmed/Desktop/azure/__init__.py", line 649, in _general_error_handler
  raise WindowsAzureError(_ERROR_UNKNOWN % http_error.message + '\n' + http_error.respbody)
  azure.WindowsAzureError: Unknown error (An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.)
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code>   <Message>An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.
 RequestId:5a839a6d-2a0f-4559-bc6d-e3b2cccf84f5
 Time:2013-11-17T13:12:03.8206435Z</Message><HeaderName>x-ms-blob-content-length</HeaderName></Error>
```

But the HTTP Header was correct:

```
   [('x-ms-blob-type', 'PageBlob'), ('Content-Encoding', None), ('Content-Language', None), ('Content-MD5', None), ('Cache-Control', None), ('x-ms-blob-content-type', None), ('x-ms-blob-content-encoding', None), ('x-ms-blob-content-language', None), ('x-ms-blob-content-md5', None), ('x-ms-blob-cache-control', None), ('x-ms-meta-name-values', None), ('x-ms-lease-id', None), ('x-ms-blob-content-length', None), ('x-ms-blob-sequence-number', None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass proper value in `x-ms-blob-content-length` request header and based on header snippet in your question above, you are passing that as `None`.

Another thing I noticed is that you're calling `put_block_list` method after pages are uploaded. Please note that this operation is not required for page blobs. As soon as `put_page` operation completes successfully, your data gets committed. `put_block_list` method is required for `Block Blobs`.

Also I noticed that your `index` variable always get incremented by 1. Shouldn't it be incremented by `PAGE_SIZE`? The way it is right now, your `x_range` variable is all screwed up. Assuming your `PAGE_SIZE` variable is `1024`, this is how the x_range variable will be:

Iteration # | index | x_range

0 | 0 | 0-1023

1 | 1 | 1-1024

2 | 2 | 2-1025

You may want to look into that as well.

==============================================

**UPDATE**

So I think I know why you are running into this problem. Basically your this line of code is causing problem:

```
blob_service.put_page(container_name, blob_name, data, x_ms_range = x_range,x_ms_page_write = 'clear')
```

If you notice, you're passing value for `x_ms_page_write` as `clear`. Change this value to `update` and your code should work fine. Based on the documentation for [`Put Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691975.aspx) operation, when you specify `clear` as value for `x_ms_page_write`, the content length should be 0. In any case, since you are uploading the page blob, the value of this header should be `update`.

Here's the code I wrote. Here I am uploading a 10 MB VHD into blob storage:

```
import sys
from azure.storage import *


def myupload(blob_service, container_name, blob_name, file_path):
    blob_service.create_container(container_name, None, None, False)
    blob_service.put_blob(container_name, blob_name, '', 'PageBlob',x_ms_blob_content_length=10486272)
    data_sent=0
    sent = 0
    block_ids = []
    index = 0
    PAGE_SIZE = 512
    pageSize = 512
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(pageSize)
            if data:
                length = len(data)
                #sys.stdout.write("\rlength = %d "%length) 
                #sys.stdout.flush()
                x_range     = 'bytes={}-{}'.format(index, index + pageSize - 1)
                sys.stdout.write("\rx_range = %s "%x_range) 
                #sys.stdout.flush()
                blob_service.put_page(container_name, blob_name, data, x_ms_range = x_range, x_ms_page_write = 'update')
                index += PAGE_SIZE
                data_sent += PAGE_SIZE
                sent = data_sent/(1024*1024)
                #sys.stdout.write("\rUploaded data = %d MB"%sent)
                #sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                break

blob_service = BlobService(account_name="myaccountname", account_key="myaccountkey")
myupload (blob_service, 'mycontainer', 'test.vhd', 'D:\\test.vhd')
```

Comment: I have modify my script before you comment but thanks for your help, also the PAGE_SIZE as mentioned in azure documentation must be 512 byte !! i do not know why .. but that i have read.

Comment: this is the output after modification: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidHeaderValue</Code><Message>The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:8f2ae87d-46e3-4d60-b884-fee92f9b0803
Time:2013-11-17T17:07:37.9286660Z</Message><HeaderName>Content-Length</HeaderName><HeaderValue>512</HeaderValue></Error>

Comment: What's the value of your PAGE_SIZE variable? Each page size should be of multiple of 512 bytes.